# Questions regarding Libraries, Open Source Projects

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked a question regarding existing solutions for RMI (Remote Method Invocation) across a network of hosts, where such a library would be able to track the hosts with a central server, while supporting [SuperPool](http://www.matrixplatform.com/index.php?title=Framework.SuperPool) style remote method invocation.

The question got tons of negativity and hate because I was asking about open source projects or libraries (I found it pretty impossible to search for existing implementations). The general feeling was that I was asking for a product recommendation, not a programming question.

What is the official opinion on this? I've seen tons of similar questions that didn't get flagged or downvoted:

- [What is the .NET standard for remote method invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560107/what-is-the-net-standard-for-remote-method-invocation)
- [Setting up a TCP/IP Client and Server to communicate over a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838421/setting-up-a-tcp-ip-client-and-server-to-communicate-over-a-network?rq=1)
- [How to call a function between two WinForm applications over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705606/how-to-call-a-function-between-two-winform-applications-over-the-network?lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Open Source. Folks just don't care for [recommendation questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/139404#139404):

> #### Ask how, not what
>
> For a library, you know what you want to accomplish, and you've presumed that finding a library that does it is the best solution - but without knowing if one even exists, that's an invalid assumption.
>
> So just ask how you should do what you want to do, and leave the library recommendations - if any - to the answerers.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503238/net-distributed-remote-method-invocation-implementation

Comment: Looks promising; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the edit as well, well noted....